# File listing problem through apache

Tags: php

I want list files of a particular directory using php exec function. I have used this

```
exec('ls /home/vikas/hft/a5/traders/sa/*.bin', $NameOfBinaries);
```

code for listing the bin files from `/home/vikas/hft/a5/traders/sa/` directory. It works fine when I run the script in CLI mode but when I run in browser it return empty array.

Comment: Please enabl error reporting and display of errors. Please add any warnings and notices you get to your question. And how do you know that `$nameOfBinaries` is empty? Please add the code in question to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Apache probably doesn't have rights to read files in your home directory.

Why not move the files somewhere that Apache can see them and use PHP's readdir() function?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the user-account -- that the webserver runs as -- has permission to read that directory.

Comment: Please don't do counter-questions in answers. Add it as a comment instead.

Comment: okay, but I believe that is the problem.  Perhaps I should have phrased it "The webserver does not have permission to read that directory"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [glob()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) PHP function instead, enabling error reporting and stopping at first error, like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1); // This is not necessary, but can add info
$nameOfBinaries = glob( '/home/vikas/hft/a5/traders/sa/*.bin', GLOB_ERR );
```

Please note: the `GLOB_ERR` flag works only with PHP versions above 5.1.0.

Moreover, this seems a permission issue, so you can check if you have the correct access permissions to the directory:

```
$handle = fopen("/home/vikas/hft/a5/traders/sa/", "r");
echo ($handle===false)? "Readable dir":"Unreadable dir";
```

This, in turn, is due to the different users under which the PHP webserver and commandline binary run, i.e. when run from the commandline, PHP inherits permissions from the currently logged user, while, when run from the web, it inherits user permissions from the webserver (Apache/ISS or whatever).

To be able to read that dir (when run from the web), appropriate permissions must be set on that directory. It must be readable from the user or group under which the webserver runs.

If you have an Apache server, in httpd.conf the `User` and `Group` directives contain respectively the user name and group name under which Apache will run.

If you cannot access server config, you should contact your system administrator asking for read permissions of that directory. A less secure option would be to set that directory (via FTP or shell)  as "world readable".

Comment: What if that function returns an empty array as well?

Comment: @hakre I added instructions and info to my original answer, hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use external functions for this, but instead use built-in PHP [directory functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php).

Answer (score 0):

How about `system`? http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php